# How to define a JSON schema for an object that has variable property names

Tags: json

I need to know how to define a JSON schema from the following example which seems to be an array but the items are variable, the list of header "numbers" goes on and on. It's a sample web response from the web service.

```
{
  "1453237200": {
    "ERRORS_OUT": null,
    "OCTETS_OUT": 229.727436984742,
    "PACKETS_OUT": 1.87192892826381,
    "DISCARDS_OUT": null,
    "SPEED": 2048000,
    "DISCARDS_IN": null,
    "PACKETS_IN": 1.83524341392888,
    "OCTETS_IN": 234.715031103113,
    "ERRORS_IN": null,
    "IFSTATUS": 1
  },
  "1453240800": {
    "ERRORS_OUT": null,
    "OCTETS_OUT": 75.3713074074074,
    "PACKETS_OUT": 0.418027777777778,
    "DISCARDS_OUT": null,
    "SPEED": 2048000,
    "DISCARDS_IN": null,
    "PACKETS_IN": 0.418567592592593,
    "OCTETS_IN": 78.1113824074074,
    "ERRORS_IN": null,
    "IFSTATUS": 1
  },
  "1453244400": {
    "ERRORS_OUT": null,
    "OCTETS_OUT": 75.2197541312908,
    "PACKETS_OUT": 0.414839344161437,
    "DISCARDS_OUT": null,
    "SPEED": 2048000,
    "DISCARDS_IN": null,
    "PACKETS_IN": 0.636818377014889,
    "OCTETS_IN": 108.708849501661,
    "ERRORS_IN": null,
    "IFSTATUS": 1
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Comment: What's the question? (Note that there's not a single array in the example.)

Comment: If your question is how to write a JSON schema, please change the title to describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a JSON array, as it does not begin and end with `[` and `]`.  It is a JSON object, where the property names can vary.  In code, you would represent this with a `Dictionary`, `Map` or associative array, depending on which language you were using.

To define a schema for this, it seems you'll need to use the `patternProperties` construct with a regex to match the variable property names, as defined in [section 5.4.4 of the JSON schema spec](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor64).  Something like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": 
    {
        "^[0-9]+$": 
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties":
            {
                "OCTETS_OUT": { "type": "number" },
                "PACKETS_OUT": { "type": "number" },
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

The JSON schema documentation shows an example of using `patternProperties` [here](http://json-schema.org/example2.html).

Comment: Hi Brian, yes this will work and my problem is half-solved. Do you know how the XML version (actually XSD) will look like from the example JSON Schema above?

Comment: Take a look at [Can't design xsd schema - because of a variable element name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2477340/10263) - I think that should help you solve the XSD part.  If not, ask a separate question.  You can link back to this question if it helps provide context.